# Php protocolo HTTPS pagina não redireciona

Tags: php, https, header

Boa tarde! Estou com um problema, ao expirar o login a página fica em branco e o comando

```
header("location: login.html"); 
exit();
```

não funciona. Isso só acontece no site com HTTPS. Alguém pode dar uma luz?

```
$valor = isset($_SESSION['MM_Admin']) ? 'S' : 'N'; 
if($valor == 'N') {
  header("location: login.html"); exit();
}
```

Comment: Amigo tenta colocar o caminho todo, tipo: https://www.seusistema/login

Comment: Aperta F12, vai em em Security e vê qual erro que da e coloque na pergunta.

Comment: Já coloquei o caminho completo e nada. No Security overview não apresenta nenhum erro.

Comment: Ja tentou dar um ini_set('display_errors', true); ?
Se algum documento estiver alterando o header antes desse código, esse código nao funciona. O header só pode ser alterado uma vez e isso gera um erro de php que o ini_set irá mostrar.